# how to get map from array of data in scala

Tags: scala

i am a newbie in scala, here i have an array variable call colarr

```
colarr: Array[(String, String)] = Array((empid,IntegerType), (empname,StringType), (address,StringType), (salary,IntegerType), (doj,TimestampType))
```

how to get individual value like empid and IntergerType from it?

Comment: What exactly is you're trying to do? Get a single value? Get some of the values? Do elaborate.

Comment: `colarr.toMap.get(empid)`?

Comment: these are column and datatype of table so i need to get the value and check its datatype

Comment: thanks Tzach, but how to iterate over each value and also it is not working it is showing error like <console>:48: error: not found: value empid
              colarr.toMap.get(empid)

Comment: `collar.map { case (id, t) => ... }` ?

Comment: insan-e can u pls explain what thing or value i need to put inplace of id or t?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to go over each tuple, you can use `Array.foreach`:

```
scala> val arr = Array(("hello", "world"), ("this", "isnice"), ("yay", "it works"))
scala> arr.foreach { 
        case (first, second) => println(s"First element $first, Second element: $second") }

First element hello, Second element: world
First element this, Second element: isnice
First element yay, Second element: it works
```

If you want to project a value from each tuple, you can use `Array.map`:

```
scala> arr.map { case (first, second) => s"$first, $second" }
res1: Array[String] = Array(hello, world, this, isnice, yay, it works)
```

The `case (first, second)` is just syntax for creating a partial function which allows you to extract the first and second element from the tuple.

If you want something simpler for starters, you can a total function and work with `_.1` and `_.2` elements of the tuple:

```
scala> arr.map(tuple => s"${tuple._1}, ${tuple._2}")
res2: Array[String] = Array(hello, world, this, isnice, yay, it works)
```

Comment: Thank you Yuval, i could able to get the value.

Comment: @anand `arr.foreach { case (first, second) => if (first == value) { // Do stuff } }`

Comment: Yuval is there any way to check if $second is numeric ??

Comment: What is the type or the tuple?